# RadGrid Dynamic DataBound Columns - Check Each Cell Value

Tags: radgrid

I have a Radgrid who has Dynamic Databound fields which comes from a database query and each time they are different. Now when this data is displayed on the GRID, i want to change the value of Cells where its 0 to " " or "."

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to hook into the CellFormatting event.  Here you can check the value of the cell and change it as required.

Something along the lines of:

```
Private Sub RadGrid_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As CellFormattingEventArgs) Handles RadGrid.CellFormatting
            if e.CellElement.RowInfo.Cells("ZeroColumn").Value = "0" then
               e.CellElement.RowInfo.Cells("ZeroColumn").Value = "."
            end if
    End Sub
```

Answer (score -3):

```
try
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1].Visible = false;
    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 3; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; ++i)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.ID = "txtRow" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString() + "Column" + i.ToString();
            tb.Width = 50;
            //if (Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row.Cells[i].Text) == false)
            //tb.Text = "0";
            //tb.Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(tb);
            // e.Row.Cells[i].Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Row.Cells[i].Text);
        }
        e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1].Visible = false;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{ }
```

Comment: answers that are just a wall of code are not that helpful, you should explain how you get to the answer

Comment: It seems like some code that would be on the RadGrid OnItemDataBound event. Not sure about it tho.